# Azure Web App staging monitoring

Tags: azure, monitoring

everyone.
Right now I'm using nice nuGet [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring) to monitor my azure web app. The code could look something like this

```
var certificate = BuildCertificate(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, " certificate thumbprint");
string subscriptionId = "subscriptionId";
string webspace = "westuswebspace";
string website = "websitename";

using (var client = new MetricsClient(new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, certificate)))
{
    var metricDefs = client.MetricDefinitions.List(ResourceIdBuilder.BuildWebSiteResourceId(webspace, website), null, null);

    var end = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var start = end.AddHours(-12);
    var timeGrain = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);

    var metricVals = client.MetricValues.List(ResourceIdBuilder.BuildWebSiteResourceId(webspace, website),
        metricDefs.MetricDefinitionCollection.Value.Select(md => md.DisplayName).ToList(), "",
                timeGrain, start, end);

    foreach (var metric in metricVals.MetricValueSetCollection.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Metric Name: {0}", metric.DisplayName);
        Console.WriteLine("Metric Namespace: {0}", metric.Namespace);
        foreach (var val in metric.MetricValues)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", val.Average.HasValue ? val.Average.Value : 0);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("//////////////////////");
    }
}
```

certificate retrieval logic

```
private static X509Certificate2 BuildCertificate(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, string thumbprint)
{
    var store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    try
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder(thumbprint.Length);
        foreach (char c in thumbprint.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit))
        {
            builder.Append(c);
        }

        string cleanThumbprint = builder.ToString();
        X509Certificate2Collection list = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, cleanThumbprint, false);

        X509Certificate2 cert;
        if (list == null || list.Count != 1)
        {
            cert = null;
        }
        else
        {
            cert = list[0];
        }
        return cert;
    }
    finally
    {
        store.Close();
    }
}
```

so, everything works perfectly fine, when I'm working with prod, but I can't figure out, how I can monitor my staging environment.
Please, help me with that. I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: What exactly isn't working in your deployment slot?